# Errors not showing up correctly on Devise Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Sign Up:

```erb
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4"> 
    <div class="devise-bootstrap-form">
      <
      <div class="devise-bootstrap-form-row">
        <div class="devise-bootstrap-form-signup">
          <h2 class="text-center">Sign up</h2>
          <%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password,
                  autocomplete: "new-password",
                  help: "(#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum)" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,
                  autocomplete: "new-password",
                  label_class: "required" %>

            <%= f.form_group do %>
              <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="text-center">
            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Log In:

```erb
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="devise-bootstrap-form">
            <div class="devise-bootstrap-form-row">
                <div class="devise-bootstrap-form-col">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Log in</h2>        
                        <%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
                            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", placeholder: 'Password' %>

                            <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                                <%= f.form_group do %>
                                    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                                <% end %>
                            <% end -%>

                            <%= f.form_group do %>
                                <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" %>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a partial to my layout which devise is currently using for logging in. Flash Partial (rendered in the application layout)

```erb
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <% if value.class == Array %>
        <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %> text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <% value.each do |message| %>  
                <%= message %>
                </br>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %>  text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <%= value %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, on the sign up it isn't using this layout and is defaulting to it's own. It never runs this partial whatsoever. What is overriding this? I want the red errors for every page as you can see by the image below.

[image: log-in devise]

However, this image below is obviously incorrect.

[image: Sign Upe]

I'm trying to work out why logging in is triggering this partial and the others are not.

Comment: where did you put your `flash` message logic? Cause I think it should be in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to make sure each view can use it if necessary.

Comment: Correct is is in layouts/application.html.erb but I put it in a partial.

Comment: so please show your signup and sign in views that would be helpful. Also show you controllers, that would help to solve the issue

Comment: yes of couse, done.

Comment: and also please your `session` and `registration` controllers

Comment: I never created them, they have been provided and hidden by devise.

Comment: please check what happen if you remove `<% if value.class == Array %>` that can be the issue